# Calcuating the proportion of total 'yes' values in a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that that looks like this:

| chr | start | end | plus | minus | total | in_control | sites_in_cluster | mean | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1005 | 6 | 7 | 13 | Y | 3 | 6 | 36346 |
| 1 | 1007 | 10012 | 3 | 1 | 4 | N | 3 | 6 | 36346 |
| 1 | 10014 | 10020 | 0 | 1 | 1 | Y | 3 | 6 | 36346 |
| 2 | 33532 | 33554 | 1 | 1 | 2 | N | 1 | 2 | 22123 |

- cluster is an ID assigned to each row, in this case, we have 3 "sites"
- In this cluster, two of these sites are in the control (`in_control==Y`)

**I want to create an additional column, which tells me what proportion of the sites are in the control.** i.e. `(sum(in_control==Y) for a cluster)/sites_in_cluster`

In this example, we have two rows with `in_control==Y` and 3 `sites_in_cluster` in cluster 36346. Therefore, cluster_sites_in_control would be `2/3 = 0.66` whereas cluster 22123 only has one site and isn't in the control, so would be `0/1=0`

| chr | start | end | plus | minus | total | in_control | sites_in_cluster | mean | cluster | cluster_sites_in_control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1005 | 6 | 7 | 13 | Y | 3 | 6 | 36346 | 0.66 |
| 1 | 1007 | 10012 | 3 | 1 | 4 | N | 3 | 6 | 36346 | 0.66 |
| 1 | 10014 | 10020 | 0 | 1 | 1 | Y | 3 | 6 | 36346 | 0.66 |
| 2 | 33532 | 33554 | 1 | 1 | 2 | N | 1 | 2 | 22123 | 0.00 |

I have created code which seemingly accomplishes this, however, it seems to be extremely roundabout and I'm certain there's a better solution out there:

```
intersect_in_control
# %%
import pandas as pd

#get the number of sites in a control that are 'Y'
number_in_control = pd.DataFrame(intersect_in_control.groupby(['cluster']).in_control.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).loc[:,'Y'])

#get the number of breaksites for that cluster
number_of_breaksites = pd.DataFrame(intersect_in_control.groupby(['cluster'])['sites_in_cluster'].count())

#combine these two dataframes
combined_dataframe =  pd.concat([number_in_control.reset_index(drop=False), number_of_breaksites.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

#calculate the desired column
combined_dataframe["proportion_in_control"] = combined_dataframe["Y"]/combined_dataframe["sites_in_cluster"]

#left join this new dataframe to the original whilst dropping undesired columns. 
cluster_in_control = intersect_in_control.merge((combined_dataframe.drop(["Y","sites_in_cluster"], axis = 1)), on='cluster', how='left')
```

10 rows of the df as example data:

```
{'chr': {0: 'chr14',
  1: 'chr2',
  2: 'chr1',
  3: 'chr10',
  4: 'chr17',
  5: 'chr17',
  6: 'chr2',
  7: 'chr2',
  8: 'chr2',
  9: 'chr1',
  10: 'chr1'},
 'start': {0: 23016497,
  1: 133031338,
  2: 64081726,
  3: 28671025,
  4: 45219225,
  5: 45219225,
  6: 133026750,
  7: 133026761,
  8: 133026769,
  9: 1510391,
  10: 15853061},
 'end': {0: 23016501,
  1: 133031342,
  2: 64081732,
  3: 28671030,
  4: 45219234,
  5: 45219234,
  6: 133026755,
  7: 133026763,
  8: 133026770,
  9: 1510395,
  10: 15853067},
 'plus_count': {0: 2,
  1: 0,
  2: 5,
  3: 1,
  4: 6,
  5: 6,
  6: 14,
  7: 2,
  8: 0,
  9: 2,
  10: 4},
 'minus_count': {0: 6,
  1: 7,
  2: 1,
  3: 5,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 2,
  9: 3,
  10: 1},
 'count': {0: 8, 1: 7, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 6, 5: 6, 6: 14, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 5, 10: 5},
 'in_control': {0: 'N',
  1: 'N',
  2: 'Y',
  3: 'N',
  4: 'Y',
  5: 'Y',
  6: 'N',
  7: 'Y',
  8: 'N',
  9: 'Y',
  10: 'Y'},
 'total_breaks': {0: 8,
  1: 7,
  2: 6,
  3: 6,
  4: 6,
  5: 6,
  6: 18,
  7: 18,
  8: 18,
  9: 5,
  10: 5},
 'sites_in_cluster': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 3,
  7: 3,
  8: 3,
  9: 1,
  10: 1},
 'mean_breaks_per_site': {0: 8.0,
  1: 7.0,
  2: 6.0,
  3: 6.0,
  4: 6.0,
  5: 6.0,
  6: 6.0,
  7: 6.0,
  8: 6.0,
  9: 5.0,
  10: 5.0},
 'cluster': {0: 22665,
  1: 24664,
  2: 3484,
  3: 13818,
  4: 23640,
  5: 23640,
  6: 24652,
  7: 24652,
  8: 24652,
  9: 48,
  10: 769}}
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

For percentage is possible symplify solution with `mean` per boolean column and for create new column use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), it working well because `True`s apre processing like `1`:

```
df['cluster_sites_in_control'] = (df['in_control'].eq('Y')
                                                  .groupby(df['cluster']).transform('mean'))

print (df)
   chr  start    end  plus  minus  total in_control  sites_in_cluster  mean  \
0    1   1000   1005     6      7     13          Y                 3     6   
1    1   1007  10012     3      1      4          N                 3     6   
2    1  10014  10020     0      1      1          Y                 3     6   
3    2  33532  33554     1      1      2          N                 1     2   

   cluster  cluster_sites_in_control  
0    36346                  0.666667  
1    36346                  0.666667  
2    36346                  0.666667  
3    22123                  0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, appreciate the simple solution!